# Wait() statement with Swing

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I have 2 buttons. 1st starts thread, 2nd makes it wait. 1st button works fine, but second doesn't want to stop 1st button thread. What's wrong? How to make it stop?

```
package SwingExp;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class WhichButton implements ActionListener {

    JLabel jLab, testLab = new JLabel();
    JFrame jfrm = new JFrame("Button example");
    JButton firstButton = new JButton("First"), secondButton = new JButton("Second");

    WhichButton() {


        jfrm.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        jfrm.setSize(220, 90);

        jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        firstButton.addActionListener(this);
        secondButton.addActionListener(this);
        jfrm.add(firstButton);
        jfrm.add(secondButton);

        jLab = new JLabel("Press button");
        jfrm.add(jLab);
        jfrm.add(testLab);

        jfrm.setVisible(true);
    }

    class SimpleThread extends Thread {
        Thread t;
        boolean suspendFlag;

        SimpleThread() {
            t = new Thread(this, "settingThread");
            t.start();

        }

        public void run() {


            for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    while (suspendFlag) {
                        try {
                            wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
                        }
                    }
                }

                testLab.setText(Integer.toString(i));

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                }

            }

            firstButton.setEnabled(true);
            testLab.setText("Completed.");
        }

        synchronized void setSuspendFlag(boolean suspendFlag) {
            this.suspendFlag = suspendFlag;
        }


    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        SimpleThread st = new SimpleThread();

        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("First")) {
            jLab.setText("First");
            firstButton.setEnabled(false);
            st.setSuspendFlag(false);

        } else {
            st.setSuspendFlag(true);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new WhichButton();
            }
        });
    }


}
```

I was trying to use `interrupt()` method, but it makes me one more thread or something like that.

Comment: Your `simplethread` creates a `thread` and is a `thread`?  Why are you doing that?  Regardless, you should read this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Swing. Doing buttons is all that I know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to `notify()` the sleeping thread in the `setSuspendFlag()` method.  otherwise, the thread will block forever in the `wait()` call.

Also, every time your buttons are pressed, you are creating a new SimpleThread instance.  you need to make the SimpleThread instance a member variable and only create it once.

Answer (score 2):

First the suspend field should be volatile
`volatile boolean suspendFlag`

and the second thing is you are synchronizing whole object, it means no any threads are allowed to use this object and its members, so simple synchronize on something else, like this

```
private Object _mutex=new Object();
public void run() {


    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        synchronized (_mutex) {
            while (suspendFlag) {
                try {
                    _mutex.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
                }
            }
        }

        testLab.setText(Integer.toString(i));

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }

    }

    firstButton.setEnabled(true);
    testLab.setText("Completed.");
}
```

and the suspending thread would be like this

```
void setSuspendFlag(boolean suspendFlag) {
    this.suspendFlag = suspendFlag;
}
```

**EDIT :** also don't forget to notify about the resume the waited thread in action performed

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    //SimpleThread st = new SimpleThread(); //what is this for?

    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("First")) {
        jLab.setText("First");
        firstButton.setEnabled(false);
        st.setSuspendFlag(false);
        try{synchronized(_mutex){_mutex.notify();}}catch(Exception){}
    } else {
        st.setSuspendFlag(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: the flag doesn't need to be volatile, and you don't need to introduce another variable to sync on.

Comment: synchronizing the whole class object `this` is not good practice, and while the first thread is doing something, no any other threads are able to call or use the object or memebrs, so this is the reason for `_mutex`, and the volatile is because possible read and direct-modify at a same time on `_mutex`, so what did I do wrong?! @jtahlborn

Comment: the `this` instance in use was that of the SimpleThread, so your use of _mutex and the original code's use of `this` were exactly equivalent, except yours was more complicated and harder to read.  syncing on `this` doesn't automatically block any other thread using the object either.  there are times when you shouldn't sync on `this`, but this isn't one of them.